# How to remove selection from a TableCell in a selected TableRow with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, selection, tablecell

I have a TableView with some columns. One column contains custom TableCell nodes. I want to remove the selection highlight from that column cell when the row is selected.

Here is the sample image which shows what I want:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom cell factory to add a style class to the cell:

```
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(name, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(name);
                }
            }
        };
        cell.getStyleClass().add("no-select-cell");
        return cell ;
    });
```

And then in an external stylesheet, revert the style for `no-select-cell` in selected rows to the defaults:

```
.table-row-cell:selected .no-select-cell {

    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}

.table-row-cell:odd:selected .no-select-cell {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt ;
}
```